# How to update/delete Object at index using Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

Today I discovered Realm and I'm not familiar with it. Please help.

I have 2 classes:

```
class EventDetail: Object {
dynamic var start_time : Int = 0
dynamic var end_time   : Int = 0
convenience init(start_time: Int, end_time: Int ) {
    self.init()
    self.start_time  = start_time
    self.end_time    = end_time
}
class Channel : Object {
  dynamic var id  : Int = 0
  convenience init ( id : Int) {
       self.id = id
  }
  let details = List<EventDetail>()
}
```

I populate the DB like this:

```
let  realm = try! Realm()
var newChannel = Channel (id : id)
let detailEvent1 = EventDetail(start_time:10, end_time:  20)                              
let detailEvent2 = EventDetail(start_time:20,end_time: 30)
newChannel.details.append(detailEvent1)
newChannel.details.append(detailEvent2)

try! realm.write {
     realm.add(newChannel)
}
```

The question is: How to  delete/update details at specific index?

Ex: get detailEvent2 from Channel where index = 100

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a fetch on the type of object you want to change or delete.

The basic operation is

```
realm.objects(Channel.self)
```

To find out which objects you want to change or delete, you can filter the result with a simple higher order function and e.g. a predicate:

```
let lateStarters = realm.objects(Channel.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "start_time > 10", argumentArray nil))
```

and change their properties by enumerating through the result array:

```
try? realm.write({
    for channel in lateStarters {
        channel.start_time = 100
    }
})
```